# Create VCard using Cardme Java

Tags: java, vcf-vcard

Hi
I am trying to create a vcard (.vcf) file in Java using Cardme API.
I can save a .vcf file, but it has no contents in it and empty. 
Please find my code below,

```
private void generateVCard(Card card){
    HelperClass helper = new HelperClass();
    VCardImpl vcard = new VCardImpl();
    BeginFeature begin = new BeginFeatureImpl();
    vcard.setBegin(begin);
    vcard.addEmail(helper.formEmailFeature(card));
    vcard.addAddress(helper.formAddress(card));
    vcard.addPhoto(helper.formPhotoFeature(card));
    vcard.addTelephoneNumber(helper.formTelephoneFeature(card));
    vcard.setName(helper.formNameFeature(card));
    vcard.setFormattedName(helper.formattedName(card));
    saveToFile("vc.vcf",vcard);
}
/**
   *  This function saves a VCard to disk.
   */
  public void saveToFile( String fileName , VCard vcard) {
      Writer output = null;   
      File file = new File("fileName");   
      try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
         output.write(vcard.toString());  
          output.flush();  
          output.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
  }
```

Appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to import the proper output class:

```
import info.ineighborhood.cardme.io.VCardWriter;
```

Or in latest versión of the library (v0.3.3) the package is:

```
import net.sourceforge.cardme.io.VCardWriter;
```

and then use it:

```
/**
     *  This function saves a VCard to disk.
     */
    public static void saveToFile( String fileName , VCard vcard) {
    Writer output = null;   
    File file = new File("fileName");   
    try {
        output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        VCardWriter writer = new VCardWriter();
        writer.setVCard(vcard);
        output.write(writer.buildVCardString());  
        output.flush();  
        output.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
    }
```

Comment: public TelephoneFeature formTelephoneFeature(Card card){
  TelephoneFeature telephoneFeature = new TelephoneFeatureImpl();
  telephoneFeature.setTelephone(card.getContact().getHmePhn());
  return telephoneFeature;
 }

Comment: Not sure what exactly that's supposed to do? The code block I put above will save the VCard output to a file.

Comment: Sorry I didnot complete my last comment completely. I tried your solution. I get the following error when I used formTelephoneFeature() method.Exception in thread "main" Caused by: info.ineighborhood.cardme.vcard.errors.VCardBuildException: TelephoneFeature (TEL) [info.ineighborhood.cardme.vcard.errors.VCardBuildException] TelephoneFeature (TEL) exists but is empty.

Comment: Thank you for your immediate response! Continuation to my post - I did set the value and with getter method printed the value on console. But still I get TelephoneFeature empty error. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Ah, that's a validation error with the library: I've not used the TelephoneFeature before. I expect you have to set one of the fields properly. Make sure for now that you set every single available field to a valid value. Once you have that working you can start leaving things out to see what is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works great. But in the Vcard file, I get the values as null:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
null:c;b;;; 
null:c
null:;;adf;cs;sca;;csc
null:121212
null:b@c.com
null;VALUE=URI:/static/images/profile_dummy.png
null:VCARD.  Is there any way that it can also show "Email" instead of null? Thanks again.

Comment: Not sure: you may need to set specific attributes in the EmailFeature to get that to display correctly. I'm surprised it doesn't do the right thing automatically, so I'm guessing you will need to dig into the javadocs and try it out. Glad it worked for you, and good luck!